# Вызвать метод класса Activity из ViewHolder

Tags: android, recyclerview

Имеем `ReciclerView`, на экране отображается список. Список обновляется каждые 5 сек. При нажатии на элемент списка, элемент расширяется (чтобы отобразить больше информации) или сужается обратно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проблема** в том, что открытый элемент сужается из-за того, что таймер работает.

Мне нужно при расширении элемента остановить таймер(`handler` или `runnable` или как он там правильно называется), а при сужении снова запустить. Для этого я написал 2 метода в `MainActivity` - `startRepeatingTask()` и `stopRepeatingTask()`, но не знаю как получить к ним доступ из класса `ViewHolder`.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ConnectionItemAdapter adapter;
    List<ConnectionItem> connectionItems;
    Handler timerHandler;
    Runnable timerRunnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        InitRecyclerView();

        timerHandler = new Handler();

        timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //тут обновляется адаптер
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000); //каждые 5 секунд
            }
        };

        timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 5000);
    }

    void startRepeatingTask()
    {
        timerRunnable.run();
    }

    void stopRepeatingTask()
    {
        timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
    }
}
```

ViewHolder.java

```
public class ConnectionItemsAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private boolean isViewExpanded = false;
    private int originalHeight = 0;

    public ConnectionItemsAdapterViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        fcuName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.FcuName);
        branchName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.FcuBranchName);
        result = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ResultText);
        versionIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.versionIcon);

        // If isViewExpanded == false then set the visibility
        // of whatever will be in the expanded to GONE

        if (isViewExpanded == false) {
            // Set Views to View.GONE and .setEnabled(false)
            branchName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            branchName.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public TextView fcuName;
    public TextView branchName;
    public ImageView versionIcon;
    public TextView result;

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        // If the originalHeight is 0 then find the height of the View being used
        // This would be the height of the cardview
        if (originalHeight == 0) {
            originalHeight = view.getHeight();
        }

        // Declare a ValueAnimator object
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator;
        if (!isViewExpanded) {
            branchName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            branchName.setEnabled(true);
            isViewExpanded = true;

            // Вот где-то тут надо остановить таймер

            valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight, originalHeight + (int) (originalHeight * 2.0)); // These values in this method can be changed to expand however much you like
        } else {
            isViewExpanded = false;
            valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight + (int) (originalHeight * 2.0), originalHeight);

            Animation a = new AlphaAnimation(1.00f, 0.00f); // Fade out

            a.setDuration(200);
            // Set a listener to the animation and configure onAnimationEnd
            a.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    branchName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    branchName.setEnabled(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

            // Set the animation on the custom view
            branchName.startAnimation(a);
        }
        valueAnimator.setDuration(200);
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                view.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
                view.requestLayout();
            }
        });
        valueAnimator.start();
    }
}
```

Только начал изучать android и java, возможно кто-то подскажет более правильный подход.

Comment: напишите `ViewHolder` в том же классе, где инициализируется `RecyclerView` (MainActivity же?), и обращайтесь как обычно: `startRepeatingTask()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Правильный способ - прокинуть интерфейс через адаптер во ViewHolder.

1. Создаём интерфейс

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void onClick();
}
```

2. Передайте его в конструктор адаптера и инициализируйте им ссылку на него в адаптере:

```
public class MyAdapter extends .... {
    private MyInterface mMyInterface;

    public MyAdapter(MyInterface myInterface) {
        mMyInterface = myInterface;
    }
}
```

3. Передавайте его также во ViewHolder при создании оного

```
public class ConnectionItemsAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private MyInterface mMyInterface;

    public ConnectionItemsAdapterViewHolder(View itemView, MyInterface mMyInterface) {
        super(itemView);
        mMyInterface = myInterface;
    }
}
```

4. В нужный момент вызовите его метод:

```
@Override
public void onClick(final View view) {
    mMyInterface.onClick();
}
```

5. При создании адаптера в активити передайте реализацию интерфейса:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(new MyInterface(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(){
        startRepeatingTask();
    }
})
```

---

А самый простой способ - кастануть контекст к активити как-то так:

```
//в классе ViewHolder
((MainActivity)itemView.getContext()).startRepeatingTask();
```

Answer (score 3):

Все очень скучно и муторно:

1. При создании адаптера `RecyclerView` в конструктор адаптера засылаем ссылку на ваш `Activity`
2. При создании `ViewHolder` также в конструкторе засылаем из адаптера ссылку на `Activity`
3. Bingo, теперь в холдере имеем `Activity` - в нужном месте вызываем методы `Activity`

Можно конечно реализовать идеологически выдержанный и православный паттерн через интерфейсы, но овчинка вряд ли стоит выделки.