# 1 activity, 2 fragments - взаимодействие

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter, android-interface

В приложении есть 1 активити с `FrameLayout`. При запуске приложения отображается `1-ый фрагмент` - `RecyclerView` с моделями новостей `NewsModel`, каждая из которых содержит поля `Title` и `Author`. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на определенный пункт `RecyclerView`, в `FrameLayout` отобразился `2-ой фрагмент` с телом новости, в которую будут переданы параметры `Title` и `Author`?

Comment: Это очень простая задача. Примеров в сети действительно много и все они работают. Если хотите что-то большее, чем ссылку на один из примеров - приведите проблемный код, то, что у вас не получается. Насколько я понял, ваша проблема лишь в том, что вы не можете программно заменить один фрагмент на другой.

Comment: Юрий, вот я попробовал сделать в отдельном приложении переходы эти - у меня получилось. Скорее всего для своего основного приложения я не понимаю, как правильно обработать нажатие по элементу recyclerview и сохранить данные модели новости для передачи их во второй фрагмент. Надеюсь выразился понятным языком :)

Comment: У RecyclerView есть какой-то слушатель нажатий на элемент. Но лучше это сделать в адаптере, прокинув туда интерфейс из активити через фрагмент. Если так сделать, то при нажатии на элемент будет вызван метод в активити, а в нём уже можно другой фргмент отобразить, передав туда данные строками/числами/объектом, реализующим Serializable/Parcelable через `fragment.setArguments()`

Comment: Юрий если вас не затруднит, напишите, пожалуйста, подробнее. Во всех примерах, что я видел, в фрагменте вызывают метод onAttach(). А как мне этот метод вызвать тогда в классе адаптера?

Comment: Ну... Там долго и нудно расписывать заново... Посмотрите тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/675943/17609