# Получить доступ к элементам RecyclerView из Activity

Tags: android, recyclerview

Пытаюсь получить доступ к элементам `RecyclerView` из `Activity` таким образом. Сначала создаю интерфейс

```
public interface ImageButtonClick {
    void clickImgButton(View v, int position);
}
```

Затем в адаптере создаю объект интерфейса

public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public ImageButton img1;

    public ListViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);
        img1 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.img1);
        img1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (imageButtonClick != null){
            imageButtonClick.clickImgButton(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}

public void setImageButtonClick(ImageButtonClick imageButtonClick) {
    this.imageButtonClick = imageButtonClick;
}
```

}

В `MainActivity` имплементирую интерфейс и пытаюсь реализовать метод интерфейса. Для начала хотя бы получить id элемента. В данном случае кнопки `ImageButton`. Но ничего не получается.

```
@Override
public void clickImgButton(View v, int pos) {
    Log.d("TTTTT", pos + "");
    Toast.makeText(this, pos + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Выбрать"), GALLERY_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: А Вы самой кнопочке слушатель назначить не забыли? А то в представленном коде что-то не видно?

Comment: это весь код, убрала только стандартные методы

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вызвать метод класса Activity из ViewHolder](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/675922/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-activity-%d0%b8%d0%b7-viewholder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю Вы забыли прикрепить слушатель к кнопке:

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {

    private ImageButtonClick imageButtonClick;

    public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public ImageButton myBtn;

        public ListViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            myBtn = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.myBtn);
            // прикрепляем слушатель к кнопке
            myBtn.setOnclickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (imageButtonClick != null){
                imageButtonClick.clickImgButton(view);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setImageButtonClick(ImageButtonClick imageButtonClick) {
        this.imageButtonClick = imageButtonClick;
    }
}
```

---

P.S.

```
public void clickImgButton(View v) {
    Log.d("TTTTT", v.getId() + "");
```

Проверять здесь `id` бессмысленно - элементы создаются из одного макета - `id` будет одинаковый. Если нужно идентифицировать элемент - передавайте дополнительно позицию в списке.

Comment: Извините метод ListViewHolder(View v) нужно добавить в активити или в адаптер?

Comment: Он у Вас есть - это конструктор холдера. Просто добавьте в него недостающую строку

Comment: Да, что-то не сообразила сразу. А чтобы идентифицировать элемент как передать позицию?

Comment: Добавьте ещё один параметр в интерфейс и передавайте при клике: `imageButtonClick.clickImgButton(view, getAdapterPosition());`.

Comment: Все равно не получилось. не реагируют кнопки на нажатия(

Comment: А реализацию интерфейса в адаптер передали (`setImageButtonClick(...)`)? Лучше делайте это через параметр конструктора адаптера - тогда точно не забудете.

Comment: public void setImageButtonClick(ImageButtonClick imageButtonClick) {
        this.imageButtonClick = imageButtonClick;
    }   в адаптере

Comment: Это я вижу, но после создании экземпляра адаптера (`ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter()`) Вы должны вызвать этот метод. `adapter.setImageButtonClick(implementation)`, передав туда ссылку на экземпляр класса, реализующего Ваш интерфейс

Comment: Получилось, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

1. В адаптере создаете интерфейс:

   public interface IFace {
   void click(View v);
   }
2. В активити реализуете этот интерфейс (implements Adapter.IFace)
3. Затем надо передать в адаптер свою активити:

   Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this);
4. Потом в onClick в адаптере проверяете реализует ли переданная активити ваш интерфейс:

   if (activity instanceof IFace){
    (IFace) activity.click(view);
   }

Это сокращенно очень. Общая суть, думаю, понятна.